# Пропали заказы Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, никто не  подскажет пропали заказы, в магазине. Как то утром защел а пропали все заказы в магазине в чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: Пропали как-то утром, а спросил только сегодня?

Comment: @rotabor Ну да, так получилось с сайтом нико не рабатал)

Comment: Консоль разработчика открой